# Get random subsection of photo

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a web app and am pretty new to web development.

Currently my program gets an and asks for user input relating to the photo.

For my project to be done I need to be able to do one of two things:

1. Select a random square in the photo and display only that portion. I want this portion of the image to change everytime the page is reloaded to show a different portion.
2. Detect a facial feature, like an eye or a mouth and show only that portion of the image.

Any free libraries or easy ways to implement either of these features?

Thank You!

Comment: 1. Do you wish to accomplish this client-side via CSS and JS or server-side with an image processing library?
2. This conversation may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291065/any-library-for-face-recognition-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

For the first question, it's relatively easy. All you need is to set the image url as the background image of a square element, say, a `<div>`, and then use JS to randomly generate a `x%` and `y%` for the `background-position: x% y%` property:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Generate random x-y coordinates
    var x = parseInt(100*Math.random(0,1)),
        y = parseInt(100*Math.random(0,1));

    // Set background-image and position
    $('#img').css({
        'background-image':'url('+$('#img').data('img-src')+')',
        'background-position':x+'% '+y+'%'
    });
});
```

For the HTML part, we take advantage of the HTML `data-` attribute:

```
<div id="img" data-img-src="/path/to/image"></div>
```

The CSS is also pretty straight forward:

```
#img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

You can see the fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/gabxj/

The second question - *what have you tried*? I did a quick search on Google and SO - [Any library for face recognition in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291065/any-library-for-face-recognition-in-javascript)

Comment: I searched, but I was looking was for suggestions on the best one, but that you for the help. I am going to try your function right now!